# apigee getnextnumber api from a number range

Tags: numbers, apigee

We are planning to use APIGEE as an api layer for our mobile application. The backend data are held in various systems like, SAP, saleforce etc. We also want to have an api getnextnumnber to return a next number on each call.  And the number should be within a range. For example the number range is 100000-999999. For example in first call the return value should be 100000 and in 2nd call the return value should be 100001 and so on. Is it possible in the apigee?

Any reply will be much appreciated.

Comment: Sort of hard to answer your question with a yes or a no without understanding your architecture and design, but for the most part, it's certainly possible with the Apigee platform if you design it appropriately. You might try asking over on the Apigee Communities site instead, and add some additional information to your question?

Comment: the managing of range of numbers can be done using APIGEE?

Comment: Apigee is an intelligent platform that supports a myriad of preconfigured policies and custom code. So yes.